# Is there a way to filter by prefix on a CMD code?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I just created a CMD line to copy all files from a specific file format (.dwg) from all folders and subfolders to another folder:

```
    for /r "from here" %a in (*.dwg) do @copy /y "%a" "to there"
```

But then I realized that I need to copy only the files starting with "EAX" prefix to prevent excessive load of useless data.

Is there a way to apply those prefix filter on this line or programming in another language is needed?

Thx!

Comment: Put "EAX" into the file specification. `for /r "from here" %a in ("EAX*.dwg") do @copy /y "%a" "to there"` Does that work for you>

Comment: When there are files with the same name in different directories, the last one copied will overwrite whatever is there. Is that acceptable?

Comment: That's nice!!! Thanks. Is it possible to do the same with a suffix? Example: all .dwg files starting with EAX and finishing with 0000, for example?

Comment: Yes, this is accepted in this case :)

Comment: Do you mean something like `EAX*0000.dwx`? What happens when you use it?

Comment: The format of the files is EAX-XXXXX-YYYY when XXXXX are sequential numbers and YYYY are 0000, 0100, 0200... In this situation, I want all the EAXs finishing with 0000.

Comment: I made it work using ("EAX**0000*.dwg") :) Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put "EAX" into the file specification.

```
for /r "from here" %a in ("EAX*.dwg") do @copy /y "%a" "to there"

for /r "from here" %a in ("EAX-*-0000.dwg") do @copy /y "%a" "to there"
```

If the middle number is always five (5) characters, you could use the following. Note that this will not check to see if the middle portion contains digits.

```
for /r "from here" %a in ("EAX-?????-0000.dwg") do @copy /y "%a" "to there"
```

Checking for exactly five (5) digits can easily be done in PowerShell. Note that the `-Filter` is a file system pattern, but `-match` uses a regex pattern.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Filter 'EAX-?????-0000.dwg' |
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^EAX\-\d{5}\-0000.dwg$' } |
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination 'C:\tmp' -Force
```